# Delta Query for Groups Not Returning Properties for New Groups Any More

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Today, code that worked last Friday is not working any more. Specifically - adding a new security group, and receiving its delta information. Steps to reproduce:

1 Create a new security group

2 Run the following C# delta code

```
var requestOptions = new List<Option>()
{
  new QueryOption("$deltatoken", deltaToken ?? "latest")
};
var deltaGroups = await _graphClient.Groups.Delta().Request(requestOptions)
        .Select("id,displayName,description,securityEnabled").GetAsync();
```

The outcome is that SecurityEnabled is null for the delta for the newly created security group. Was there a recent change (deployment) to Graph that changed the original behavior? (because User delta still works as before, Groups looks like it defaults to Prefer:return=minimal instead)

Comment: are you still experiencing the same issue? Could you provide a request id please?